# Transformar a LinQ

Tags: sql, linq

Alguien me puede ayudar a convertir la consulta SQL a LinQ, no sé como hacerlo. Aquí les dejo la consulta:

```
select s.id,
       p.code as product_code, 
       p.description,
       pt.code as productype_code
                    
  from stock s  inner join product p
    on p.id = s.productid  inner join producttype pt
    on pt.id = p.producttypeid  inner join container cn
```

Me resultaría útil aprender Linq.
Gracias

Comment: Justamente para aprender, ¡debes intentarlo! ¿Qué problemas has tenido para convertir la consulta? Ponlo tanto en el título como en la propia pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: hola, pues deconozco la sintaxis básica de linq, y por lo tanto su transformacion

Comment: [Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/) puedes aprender la sintaxis básica de linq. Luego puedes transformar el sql a linq